# Saving email attachments automatically with a specific subject title

Tags: vba, email, outlook

Hope someone can shed some light on to this for me.

I have written a script which should save an email attachment with a specific heading (I have this part specified in the rules section of outlook, or should it be written into the script?)

For some reason it isn't working.  Below is the script I have: -

```
Public Sub saveAttachmentTtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment

Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "C:/LocationOfFolderToSaveTo"
For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
    Set objAtt = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

Can anyone see where  I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> saveFolder = "C:/LocationOfFolderToSaveTo"

Should be **`saveFolder = "C:\LocationOfFolderToSaveTo\"`**

---

To specify by subject line - try adding `IF function`  to check if the specified condition is being met or not

```
If olItem.Subject = "Subject line here" Then
```

---

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Save_Attachment(olItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim olAttch As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim sPath As String

    'sPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\"
    sPath = "C:\Temp\"

    For Each olAttch In olItem.Attachments
        If olItem.Subject = "0m3r" Then
            olAttch.SaveAsFile sPath & "\" & olAttch.DisplayName
        End If
    Next

    Set olAttch = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you - I will give this a try @ Om3r

Comment: I am not sure if it worked yet, will need to test it when I am back in work.  I will accept it worked or comment if not. @Om3r

Comment: If you think a new user may not be aware of the accept procedure you may try pointing them to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work as described here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297597/what-to-do-with-user-asking-for-upvote-and-accept